# Line-breaks in between of text using JS ,(Dynamically)

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic

I am stuck on a very beginner problem in JS, what I'm trying to do is add line-breaks in between text which the script adds dynamically after generating a random string, but I could not find a source that would match my case

**The code that picks a random string**

```
var textArray = [
    'Gateway to wild imaginations!',
    'Activating the send portal :D',
    'Empowering nothing ;P'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);
var rndStr = textArray[randomNumber];

const h_1_elem = document.getElementById('main-h1');
h_1_elem.innerText = rndStr;
```

***I would consider myself a beginner in programming so take this question with a pinch of salt***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use \n to insert a new line since you are using

```
h_1_elem.innerText = rndStr + "\n";
```

Also I created a function called randomNumber in order to call it more than one time.

```js
var textArray = [
    'Gateway to wild imaginations!',
    'Activating the send portal :D',
    'Empowering nothing ;P'
];

const h_1_elem = document.getElementById('main-h1');
h_1_elem.innerText = textArray[randomNumber()] + "\n";
h_1_elem.innerText += textArray[randomNumber()] + "\n";

function randomNumber() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);
  return number;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-h1"></div>
```

If you run the code multiple times, you will get different messages. Just keep adding more :)

Regards

============ EDITED ============

Oh, you want a break line after each word. Didn't understand the question that way. So, for that you should use something like this:

```js
var textArray = [
    'Gateway to wild imaginations!',
    'Activating the send portal :D',
    'Empowering nothing ;P'
];

const h_1_elem = document.getElementById('main-h1');
h_1_elem.innerText = textArray[randomNumber()].replaceAll(" ","\n");

function randomNumber() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);
  return number;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-h1"></div>
```

I just used

```
replaceAll(" ", "\n")
```

In order to replace every space by a break line. Hope this is what you want.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo but I want to print a line break **in between** the text of h_1_elem

Comment: Hello Zippy, edited the answer to match what I understand you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.innerText` and instead use `.innerHTML` along with the HTML line break element of `<br>`:

```js
var textArray = [
    'Gateway to wild imaginations!',
    'Activating the send portal :D',
    'Empowering nothing ;P'
];

var rndStr = textArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length)];

const h_1_elem = document.getElementById('main-h1');
h_1_elem.innerHTML = rndStr + "<br>";
rndStr = textArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length)];
h_1_elem.innerHTML += rndStr + "<br>";
```

```html
<div id="main-h1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man! but I want to print a line break **in between** the text this prints a <br> after the iteration.